# React Native | Default Set Width Style

Tags: react-native, view, styles

I noticed that while adding 'View' with React native, it behaves as if "width: '100%'" was assigned even though I did not enter any style. Same situation exists for any component. It covers the whole area horizontally. What is the cause and solution?

```
    return (
        <View style={{flex:1}}>
            {/* paints the line he is in full red but should only paint as much as the line of the text */}
            <View style={{backgroundColor:'red'}}> 
                <Text>Example</Text>
            </View >
        </View>
    );
```

Comment: Please specify what you want rather than `width: 100%`

Comment: I don't want to enter width for every element. I don't think you will be responsive.

Comment: No. Code as attached only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the background color to only encompass the text, you can use this:

```
<Text style={{backgroundColor: 'red', alignSelf: 'flex-start'}}>
    Example
</Text>
```

Comment: Thank you, it was a solution. Do you know the reason for this? This is the first time I have met Unless I have given any width or flex I know so far, it wouldn't go completely horizontally.

Comment: In react native, the default value of the width of View is 'auto' because you didn't set it to anything else ('auto' basically 100% of the remaining space of the parent unless other styles make it behave otherwise ie: flex).